# avg of a sum in mySQL. I did see similar answer but I applied it and it does not work for me

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT AVG (TotalHWCostPerComputer.OptionalHardwareCost)
(SELECT cmpt_name, SUM(cost) AS OptionalHardwareCost FROM computer
NATURAL JOIN computer_hardware
NATURAL JOIN hardware
GROUP BY cmpt_name) AS TotalHWCostPerComputer
```

I got this error

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(SELECT cmpt_name, SUM(cost) AS OptionalHardwareCost FROM computer
>   NATURAL JOIN ' at line 2

I run the innner select by itself and it ran fine

```
SELECT cmpt_name, SUM(cost) AS OptionalHardwareCost FROM computer
NATURAL JOIN computer_hardware
NATURAL JOIN hardware
GROUP BY cmpt_name
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the `from` keyword

```
SELECT AVG(TotalHWCostPerComputer.OptionalHardwareCost)
from
( 
   SELECT cmpt_name, SUM(cost) AS OptionalHardwareCost
   FROM computer
   NATURAL JOIN computer_hardware
   NATURAL JOIN hardware
   GROUP BY cmpt_name
) AS TotalHWCostPerComputer
```

Answer (score -1):

You're building

```
SELECT foo (SELECT bar ... )...
```

which means the sub-query stuff is being treated as an invalid **ALIAS** for the `foo` field. You need

```
SELECT foo, (SELECT bar ...) ...
          ^---forgot this
```

Comment: That was my first impression of the error too, but sorry, I have to downvote this.

Comment: ah yeah. guess it would be table sub-query, not a field sub-query.